# Getting "KeyNotFoundException" and "Can not find view for" when trying to start MvvmCross App in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

Trying to follow slodges n-22 tutorial and when trying to run the app I am getting a KeyNotFoundExcpetion and a message stating "Can not find view for...." when I try to call the .Start() method.

Can it not find the assemblies with ViewModels in them?  I'm guessing because the key was not found that the generic list/dictionary did not get filled with ViewModels?

Comment: 'can not find the view for' sounds like a view rather than viewmodel problem. Will try to help - but it's hard to tell from this current post. If possible, please post much more detailed info about what problem you are seeing (eg a full error trace), which platform(s) you are working on, what state your code is currently in and what version of xamarin tools you are using (alpha, beta or stable) - also, maybe try comparing your code against the finished N+1 repo?

Comment: Thanks for the response Stuart!  I figured out what the issue was, very simple so sorry if I wasted your time!  The model class name did not have ViewModel as part of the name, just Model.  So I'm guessing "Model" is stripped from the class name and that should be the view name.  Probably in a doc somewhere so my apologies!